# Get the max column value for each unique ID

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group, maxdate

I have two tables, a `customers` and `orders` table.

The `customers` table contains a unique `ID` for each customer. It contains 1141 entries.

The `orders` table contains many entries with a `customerID` and a `date`.

I am trying to query my database and return a list of customers and the `max(date)` from the orders list.

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerID, max(date) as date
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) Sub1
ON customers.id = Sub1.CustomerID
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.CustomerID = Sub1.CustomerID
AND orders.date = Sub1.Date
```

However this query is returning 1726 rows instead of 1141 rows. Where is this getting extra from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are ties.

For a given customer, some place more than one order per day. So there's a possibility that occasionally some may have placed more than one order on the date that is their max date.

To fix this, you need to use `MAX()` or some column that is **always unique in the Orders table** (or at least unique within a given date). This is easy if you can depend on an auto-increment primary key in the Orders table:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT CustomerID, max(orderid) as orderid as date
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
) Sub1
ON customers.id = Sub1.CustomerID
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.CustomerID = Sub1.CustomerID
AND orders.orderid = Sub1.orderid
```

This assumes that orderid increases in lock-step with increasing dates. That is, you'll never have an order with a greater auto-inc id but an earlier date. That might happen if you allow data to be entered out of chronological order, e.g. back-dating orders.

Comment: So essentially, this selects the max date from the max orderid from each customer?

Comment: It doesn't select dates, it selects orderids. If orderids are assigned in chronological order, then it naturally corresponds with the max date for each customer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's beacause ORDERS table contains same customerID multiple times, so when you join the table with CUSTOMERS, each CUSTOMER.id matches multiple rows of ORDERS.

Comment: +1 Specifically, there may be multiple orders per customer on the given date that is that customer's max date.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, how can I return only one though?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as
(
  select CustomerID, orderdate
      , rn = row_number() over (partition by customerID order by orderdate desc)
from orders
)

select c.*, cte.orderdate
from customer c
 join cte on cte.customerID = c.customerid 
where rn =1 -- This will limit to latest orderdate
```

Comment: MySQL does not support windowing functions like `row_number()`.